# Is $\sum_{\substack{s\:\ge\:0\\\Delta X_s\:\ne\:0}}1_B(s,\Delta X_s)$ measurable for fixed $B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty)\times\mathbb R)$?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a càdlàg Lévy process on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0},\operatorname P)$ and $B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty)\times\mathbb R)$.

> How can we show that $$\pi:=\sum_{\substack{s\:\ge\:0\\\Delta X_s\:\ne\:0}}1_B(s,\Delta X_s)$$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable?

$(\Delta X_s)_{s\ge0}$ is clearly $(\mathcal F_s)_{s\ge0}$-adapted and hence $$\Omega\to\{0,1\}\;,\;\;\;\omega\mapsto1_{\{\:\Delta X_s\:\ne\:0\:\}}(\omega)1_B(s,\Delta X_s(\omega))\tag1$$ is $\mathcal F_s$-measurable for all $s\ge0$. Moreover, $$\{s\ge0:\Delta X_s(\omega)\ne0\}\tag2$$ is countable for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

> Now we might be tempted to argue that $\pi$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable as the countable sum of $\mathcal A$-measurable functions. However, $(2)$ is only a countable set for each **fixed** $\omega\in\Omega$. And in order to apply the former argument, we would need that there is a countable $D\subseteq[0,\infty)$ with $$\pi(\omega)=\sum_{s\in D}1_{\{\:\Delta X_s\:\ne\:0\:\}}(\omega)1_B(s,\Delta X_s(\omega))\;\;\;\text{for all }\omega\in\Omega.\tag3$$ Can we fix this issue?

---

As usual, $x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$ and $\Delta x(t):=x(t)-x(t-)$ for all $t\ge0$ and càdlàg $x:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$.

**Remark**: I've asked [this qustion on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4341779/47771), but I didn't receive an answer (even after a bounty expired). For some reason, I cannot delete the question on MSE at the moment, but I will as soon as it is possible.

Comment: Please refer to the book "J. Jacod, and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003" Prop. II.1.16, p.69. This proposition answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is routine (and I am quite sure covered by standard textbooks), although somewhat tedious. First, for a compactly supported, non-negative and continuous $f$, one writes
$$ \tag{1} S_t[f] := \sum_{s \leqslant t} f(s, X_{s-}, X_s) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor n t\rfloor} f(\tfrac in, X_{(i-1)/n}, X_{i/n}) , $$
which shows that the left-hand side is measurable. Next, for an open and bounded $B$, one approximates the sum of $\mathbb 1_B(s, \Delta X_s)$ by $S_t[f]$ for an appropriate sequence of functions $f$. Finally, one uses the monotone class theorem, or Dynkin's lemma, to show measurability for all Borel sets $B$.

---

*Remark.* Judging by your previous questions, as well as the emphasized part of this question, you seem to be confused by the use of different $\sigma$-algebras. The above construction does not work in the framework of the product $\sigma$-algebras on the space $\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ of *all* paths, because the set of càdlàg paths is not measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra. Instead, one works with $D([0, \infty), \mathbb R)$, the class of *càdlàg* paths, with the "cylindrical" $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ (which is just the previous product $\sigma$-algebra restricted to the non-measurable subset $D([0, \infty), \mathbb R)$). Finally, one augments this $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ with respect to an appropriate probability measure (or at least one considers the $\sigma$-algebra of universally measurable sets) in order to have various objects (such as hitting times) measurable.

---

*Edit — a sketch of the proof of (1):* This is a pathwise result.

We may restrict our attention to a finite time horizon: $t \in [0, T]$ for $T$ large enough, so that $f(s, x, y) = 0$ when $s \geqslant T$. Choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(s, x, y) = 0$ if $|x - y| < \epsilon$, and enumerate all jumps of $X_s$ of size larger than $\tfrac\epsilon2$: these times form an increasing sequence $s_k$. Call $X_t'$ the same path as $X_t$, but with all jumps at times $s_k$ removed:
$$ X_t' = X_t - \sum_{k : s_k \leqslant t} \Delta X_{s_k} . $$
Then $|\Delta X_t'| \leqslant \tfrac\epsilon2$ for all $t$.
As in the proof of uniform continuity of continuous functions, one has the following property (see below for a proof): $$ \tag{2} \text{there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $|t_1 - t_2| < \delta$, then $|X_{t_1}' - X_{t_2}'| < \epsilon$.} $$ (Here, of course, $0 \leqslant t_1, t_2 \leqslant T$.)

Suppose that $\tfrac1n<\epsilon$. Then it follows that $f(\tfrac in, X_{(i-1)/n}, X_{i/n}) \ne 0$ only if the interval $[\tfrac{i-1}n, \tfrac in]$ contains some $s_k$ (for otherwise the increments of $X_t$ on this interval are equal to the increments of $X_t'$). The desired result follows now easily by continuity of $f$.

---

Proof of (2): Suppose, contrary to our claim, that no such $\delta$ exists, and let $p_n, q_n$ satisfy $|p_n - q_n| < \tfrac1n$ and $|X_{p_n}' - X_{q_n}'| \geqslant \epsilon$. By passing to a subsequence, we may assume that $p_n$ and $q_n$ converge to some limit $s$, and it follows that necessarily $|\Delta X_s'| \geqslant \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've actually didn't found this statement in a lecture book. Do you've got a reference in mind? I've actually struggle to prove why your identity is correct and asked for it on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4348849/47771. (BTW, I guess you've intended to write $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor n t\rfloor} f(X_{(i-1)/n}\color{red}-X_{i/n})$ on the right-hand side.)

Comment: Have you seen Lemma 20.9, and the proof of the Lévy–Itô decompositon that follows after it, in Sato's book? This is perhaps not the very same statement, but it contains what you are looking for (with a different argument, perhaps). Also, I corrected the typo, but it is different from what you suggested: $f$ is a function of three variables.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I've seen this in Sato's book before, but I would actually prefer to understand why your identity is true. Could you take a look at my MSE post in my first comment?

Comment: Please refer to the book "J. Jacod, and A. N. Shiryayev, Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes, 2ed. Springer, 2003" Prop. II.1.16, p.69. This proposition answer your question.

Comment: @JGWang Thank you for your comment. I've taken a look into that proposition, but unless I'm missing something, it doesn't answer how we can show the identity described and which I've asked for in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348849/if-x-is-a-c%c3%a0dl%c3%a0g-function-and-f-has-compact-support-how-can-we-approximate. To be honest, it shouldn't be rather elementary to solve the remaining issue I've described there, but I wasn't able to figure out how at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. What exactly do you mean by "removing all jumps of size larger than $\varepsilon/2$? How do you remove them, i.e. how do you exactly obtain $X'$ from $X$?

Comment: Besides that, I don't understand the rest of your argumentation. You say "by the usual proof of uniform continuity of continuous functions", but the paths of $X$ are not continuous. They are only right-continuous and have left limits.

Comment: Is it any better now?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I already thought about the argument you've used to prove (2). But my problem with that argument is that it seems like you're assuming that the subsequences of $p_n$ and $q_n$ approach $s$ from the left and right, respecitvely. But I don't think that we can assume this. Why shouldn't they both, for example, be increasing?

Comment: Come on: we have $\limsup_{p,q\to s} |X_p-X_q| \geqslant \epsilon$, and so necessarily $\Delta X_s| \geqslant \epsilon$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I'm sorry for the late response. I wasn't able to come back to this problem until now. I'm not sure if I'm really missing something, but I'm only able to condlude $|\Delta X_s|\ge\color{red}2\varepsilon$ from $\limsup_{p,q\to s} |X_p-X_q| \geqslant \epsilon$. So, are you really sure?

Comment: That would be even better, would it not. But $\epsilon$ is correct: $\limsup_{p,q\to s}|X_p-X_q| = |\Delta X_s|$ for every càdlàg path $X_t$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki You're right. I was trying to prove too less. If $r:=\|\Delta x(\tau)\|$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then we find $\delta_1>0$ with $\|x(\tau)-x(t)\|<r$ for all $t\in(\tau-\delta_1,\tau)$ and $\delta_2>0$ with $\|x(\tau)-x(t)\|<\varepsilon$ for all $t\in[\tau,\tau+\delta_2)$. Thus, $\|x(s)-x(t)\|<r+\varepsilon$ for all $s,t\ge0$ with $|s-\tau|\wedge|t-\tau|<\delta_1\wedge\delta_2$; which is equivalent to $\limsup_{s,t\to\tau}\|x(s)-x(t)\|=r$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Are you sure that we need to assume that $f$ is compactly supported? I think the claim should be true for every continuous $f:E\to F$, $E$ and $F$ Banach spaces, such that $0\not\in\operatorname{supp}f$. Then, if $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ is càdlàg and $a=t_0<\cdots<t_n=b$, it should hold $\sum_{i=1}^nf(x(t_i)-x(t_{i-1}))\to\sum_{t\in(a,\:b]}f(\Delta x(t))$ as $\max_{1\le i\le n}(t_i-t_{i-1})\to0$.

Comment: Everything in my answer is real-valued, no Banach spaces around. And yes, this can be extended to more general $f$, but why bother?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Sorry for bothering you again with this basic question, but I got trouble to understand how you intend to approximate the sum to obtain the result I've asked for in the question. I've posted a [separate question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4407224/47771) for that. Would be great if you could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a complement of above comment.

To discuss the measurability of $\pi$, the following conclusion is helpful(cf.  C. Dellacherie & P. Meyer, *Probabilities and Potential*, volume 29 of *North-Holland Mathematics Studies*. North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1978. Theorem VI.88B, p.140).

**Theorem** Let  $X=\{X_t,t\ge0\}$ be a real valued, càdlàg adapted  process, $X_{0-} =X_0$, and $D=\{(\omega,t): X_{t-}(\omega)\ne X_t(\omega)\}$. Then $D$ is a countable union of disjoint graph of stopping times, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
    D=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}[\hspace{-1pt}[ T_n]\hspace{-1pt}].   \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

One fact should be mention is that, the conclusion is no matter the completeness of $\mathscr{A},(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t\ge 0} $. Hence, $T_n$ is also $\mathscr{A}$-measurale.

Using (1), rewrite $\pi$ as following:
\begin{align*}
    \pi(\omega,B)&= \sum_{s>0}1_{\{\Delta X_s\ne 0\}}(\omega)1_B(s,\Delta X_s(\omega))\\
    &=\sum_{n\ge1} 1_B(T_n(\omega), \Delta X_{T_n(\omega)}(\omega) ). \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Due to the $X$ is càdlàg adapted  process, $X$ and $X_-=(X_{t-}, t\ge 0), \Delta X$ are measurable processes, i.e., $X$ and $X_-, \Delta X$ are
$\mathscr{A}\otimes\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}_+)$-measurable. Furthermore, $\Delta X_{T_n(\omega)}(\omega),  
 1_B(T_n(\omega), \Delta X_{T_n(\omega)}(\omega))$ and $\pi(\omega,B)$, all are $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that the process $(X_t)$ is adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$.)

Because $X$ is cadlag, the set $J_n(\omega):=\{t>0: |\Delta X_t(\omega)|>1/n\}$ is locally finite for each $\omega$ and each $n\ge 1$.
It can be "exhausted" by a sequence of stopping times $\{T_{nk}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ defined by $T_{n0}:=0$ and
$$
T_{n,k+1}:=\inf\{t>T_{nk}: \Delta |X_t|>1/n\},\qquad k=0,1,\ldots.
$$
For a Borel set $B$, and each $n$ and $k$, the function
$$
\pi_{nk}:\omega\mapsto 1_B(T_{nk}(\omega),\Delta X_{T_{nk}}(\omega))1_{\{T_{nk}(\omega)<\infty\}}
$$
is $\mathcal A$ measurable, hence so is the countable sum
$$
\pi_n:=\sum_{k\ge 1}\pi_{nk}1_{\{T_{nk}<\infty\}}.
$$
Finally,  $\pi_n$ increases pointwise to $\pi$ as $n\to\infty$,  so $\pi$ is also $\mathcal A$ measurable.